# C++ The loop in my switch format isn't allowing me to display menu options or accept input?

Tags: c++, xcode, loops, menu, switch-statement

I'm needing to write a loan program for a course and I have this bit of code thus far:

```
    /*
    Project: Course Project - Loan Calculator
    Program Description: To calculate customer's loan
 information including interest rate, monthly
 payment and number of months payments will be
 required for.
 Developer: ___________
 Last Update Date: June 1st, 2020
 */

#include <iostream>
#include <string>


//variables listed here
double loanAmt = 0, intRate = 0, loanLength = 0;
std::string CustName[0];
int choice; //menu choice identifier


using namespace std;
int main()
{
    //Welcome User
    cout << "Thank you for using our calculator." << endl;
    cout << endl;
    cout << "Please enter the number of your preferred calculator and press 'Enter': " << endl;
    cout << endl;
    cin >> choice;

    {
        while (choice !=4);
        switch (choice)
        {
            case 1:
                cout << "Monthly Payment Calculator:";
                cout << endl;
                break;
            case 2:
                cout << "Interest Rate Calculator:";
                cout << endl;
                break;
            case 3:
                cout << "Payment Term (In Months):";
                cout << endl;
            case 4:
                cout << "Exit Calculator:";

            default: //all other choices
                cout << "Please Select A Valid Option.";
                break;

        }
    }
}
```

I've tried moving the cin << choice; to many different spots, including inside of the while loop written for the switch, but I can only seem to get it to show the prompt for the menu, but not the menu options themselves and it isn't taking input. If it makes a difference, I'm using Xcode for the first time and I need it to run there as I can't run C++ on my version of Visual studio (on Mac). Where may I have gone wrong here and any insight into why my version is wrong is appreciated as I'm still very new to coding overall. Thank you.

Comment: You are working with characters. Use while(... '4' ) instead of 4, case '1' instead of 1 and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You had this:

```
while (choice !=4);
```

This makes it so that your code never continues further than this while loop. Unless your compiler removes this line during optimization.

This is the correct way:

```
    while (choice !=4) {
        switch (choice)
        {
            case 1:
                cout << "Monthly Payment Calculator:";
                cout << endl;
                break;
            case 2:
                cout << "Interest Rate Calculator:";
                cout << endl;
                break;
            case 3:
                cout << "Payment Term (In Months):";
                cout << endl;
            case 4:
                cout << "Exit Calculator:";

            default: //all other choices
                cout << "Please Select A Valid Option.";
                break;

        }
        cin >> choice; // have it right after the switch
   }
```

Comment: It does, thank you so much! I got it fixed now and just have to make the default not show immediately and the menu to display the prompts. I appreciate that.

Comment: @FeeFae, no problem, I am glad that I could help. Could you please mark my asnwer as the answer for the question?

Comment: Sure! Sorry, new on the site, but I'll do it now!